# What name might "B." indicate in 16th or 17th century Germany?

Tags: germany, church-records, abbreviations

I've run across the abbreviated name "B." in the oldest church books I am working with.  I don't think I've seen it used after around the middle of the 17th century, but I've seen it in entries in the marriage and funeral books between the 1570s and 1640.  These are the oldest people still alive at the time, so they'd have been born likely before 1570, and at a time before baptism records were kept, so I cannot see their baptismal names.  So far, I've noticed the following:

- B. Michael
  [image]
- B. Adam
  [image]
- B. Baltzar
  [image]
  [image]
- B. Conrad
- B. Elias
  [image]
  [image]
- B. Eÿlias Friderich
  [image]
- B. Frederich
  [image]
- B. Sebastian
  [image]

I have only seen this abbreviated name style for "B."; no other letter.

Was there some common "B" name such that an abbreviated "B" would make sense?  What name did this indicate?

Examples in context:

- [1635 burials, 3rd from bottom, left side](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MesjbLhsnTo-nJAl6mRSZZ6kCLkD8W5q/view?usp=sharing)
- [1636 burials, 3 entries on the right side, at top, middle, and 3rd from bottom](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F9pNI_4ko_bzJf9OQ3TfAsdb2iRkH41U/view?usp=sharing)
- [1621 baptisms, 6th from bottom on left side](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1foYrzp8Z6LBLUx0efQ9p8MXhbsYRGbUf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: In more recent books, there are sometimes abbrevations for some social/legal status (eg citizen). Could this indicate someone who is a Bürger of that place? Do you know whether this distinction exists for that time and location?

Comment: I think it's not an abbreviation of a name. Do you have an example how it's used in a marriage record? If it's an indication of social status (like Bauer, for example), then it should be used in other records as well, including baptism and marriages. If it's only used with death records, then it's probably something else.

Comment: Reviewing my notes, let me correct myself.  You're correct, I've only seen it in funeral records, not with marriages.  That said, however, the records only start about 1574, and these guys were all already born, baptised, and married by that point, so I wouldn't take the lack of such a record as specifically indicative.  The last of them that I've noticed died in 1636, with no new "B. ___" people being baptised/married after 1574.

Comment: Very interesting. Do all persons have this B., or are there some without it? Modern citizenship did not exist at that point. As this is already past the Reformation, it might indicate the religion of the person? Is the B. only present for men?

Comment: Only a small number have it; easily under 5%, and only men.  This is from Creuzburg, in Thuringia, so Lutheranism was already dominant here by that time.  (Placing this in time, at least one of the priests writing these records would have been Michael Praetorius' father.)

Comment: If it's only used in funeral records, then it might be from Latin Beatus = selig, verstorben. 

See: https://www.sudetendeutsche-familienforscher.de/genealogische-abkuerzungen/?name_directory_startswith=B#name_directory_position

But this does not explain why only some have it and others not. There has to be some additional explanation.

Comment: I just noticed that the third example (Baltzar) is for the wife of "Baltzar Nordman" (or similar). In this case the "B." could indeed indicate that the spouse died earlier. One might expect "Catharina, xxx Witwe [widow]" instead of "Catharina, xxx Weib [wife]" in that case, but the phrasing might depend on era and locality.

Comment: @BrianFreud, could you provide larger snippets for these examples? I think the context  as well as the appearance of the other entries are important for us to solve this question.

Comment: @jadepx Sure, I've edited in a few examples in context.  I also found one example on a baptism record, which is included in those examples.  For that particular example, "B. Sebastian Braunschweig", I've not found any direct record for him, only the two examples given here, so I cannot say when he died, though presumably it would have been after ~Jan of 1621.

Comment: Also, to expand the date range, I've found one last use of the "B." in 1645, as pictured above, also in a burial record.  As a side note, I've most recently been working through the earliest records (1619-1741) from a neighboring town, and have not seen a single "B." entry.

Comment: It's Sebastian Breithaupt, not Braunschweig! Apparently several members of the Breithaupt family, including the brothers Elias and Sebastian and their father Friedrich were Bürgermeisters in Creuzburg. Could this explain the abbreviation?

Comment: Ah, you're right; there's both Breithaupts and Braunschweigs in town, and its been all to easy to misread one as the other.  :D  As for Bürgermeister, I was actually thinking 'perhaps Bürger' last night, but couldn't find anything on citizenship in towns of that era.  Bürgermeister might solve the problem of so few being marked as "B." though it seems odd that only Creuzburg, and not the surrounding cities, would so indicate...

Comment: In my experience, entries for "important" people (mayor, clergy) are often more elaborate and would not abbreviate that status, but I'm mostly working with newer (18th/19th century) books. What just occurred to me: Sometimes the author gives an explanation of the used entry scheme somewhere in the book (first or last pages). Is there something like this in the respective books?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any such 'explainer' text that I've seen.

Comment: Going through the earliest records in Mihla and Lauterbach, the priest didn't use a "B." prefix.  However, he did use "Weÿland" and "Weÿl." in a similar manner.  I think he meant "weiland", to indicate that the person being named was deceased.  I'm thinking that "B." was used in a similar manner, short perhaps for "begraben".

Comment: So in a couple of entries, this seems duplicate information then (someone in a burial record is supposed to be dead). But it's the most likely explanation after all, I guess.